# Forbid QDialog to be moved by the user

Tags: python, qt, pyside, pyside6

I want to disable that the user can move a displayed custom QDialog. I could not find a solution while googling. Maybe move is the wrong term as it showed many results based on the mouse move event.

I need to use a non-frameless dialogue because I need the close button.

Comment: Perhaps you can subclass the dialog and use its `moveEvent` function to always return the dialog to the same place..

Comment: This requirement goes against standard dialog behavior on most operating systems (at least on Linux and Windows; on macOS it is the standard I think) and is very unexpected from the users' perspective. Just out of curiosity: Why do you think this is a good idea? Why do you want/need this? Why don't you just leave it to be handled by the operating system the standard way?

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager I implemented an image preview dialogue that is displayed on a 720p touchscreen. So when the user clicks on a thumbnail on the main screen, the image is enlarged within this dialogue. But a request from QA is that the user should not be able to move the popup. Perhaps there is a better solution than a QDialog?

Comment: @sebwr What OS are you on?

Comment: @sebwr Maybe you can just show the image in full screen or as maximized, if you need a way to close the dialog, just use a layout manager (a vertical box should be fine) and add a button on a top corner, or eventually overlay it over the image, then connect it's `clicked` signal to the window `close()` function.

Comment: @sebwr Why do you need a ***title-bar*** close button? You can easily add your own button for closing the preview. It sounds like your preview widget is not, in fact, a dialog, so it should not look or behave like one. Specifically, it should not have a title-bar, which will usually have extra functionality supplied by the window-manager.

Comment: Why not tell the UX designer it should be a frameless window?

Comment: @HiFile.app-bestfilemanager Linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: I will test with custom close button and frameless window